# Event is fired but text doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf

What im trying to do is to change Splash window label content. 
App code behind is as follows

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private const int splashMinTime = 2000;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Splash splashScr = new Splash();
        splashScr.Show();

        splashScr.SplashInfo = "Ładowanie ....";

        Stopwatch splashTimer = new Stopwatch();
        splashTimer.Start();
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

        splashTimer.Stop();

        int splashRemainingTime = splashMinTime - (int)splashTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        if (splashRemainingTime > 0)
            Thread.Sleep(splashRemainingTime);

        splashScr.Close();
    }
}
```

Splash

```
public partial class Splash : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _SplashInfo;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Splash()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string SplashInfo
    {
        get { return _SplashInfo; }
        set { _SplashInfo = value; OnPropertyChanged("SplashInfo"); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And my Splash.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="Img\Splash.jpg" Stretch="None"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblSplashInfo" Content="{Binding SplashInfo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,204,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220"/>
</Grid>
```

Splash PropertyChangedEventHandler is fired but i don't see the changes in the splash window label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a treading issue as Marcel_Bonzelet said. Try this and you will see:

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            window.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            new Task(() =>
            {
                Splash splashScr = null;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    splashScr = new MainWindow();
                    splashScr.Show();
                });
                Stopwatch splashTimer = new Stopwatch();
                splashTimer.Start();

                splashScr.SplashInfo = "Ładowanie ....";

                splashTimer.Stop();

                int splashRemainingTime = splashMinTime - (int)splashTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                if (splashRemainingTime > 0)
                    Thread.Sleep(splashRemainingTime);

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    splashScr.Close();
                    window.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                });
            }).Start();

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
```

Some explanation: the OnStartup method is called on the same thread where your label would be updated. So if you block this thread, and after that you immediately close the window, you won't be able to see the result of the binding.

Comment: This worked, kinda.... Yes, the label did change, but now i got two main waindows and splash is under them. Splash is created, than instantly first instance of Main window on top of Splash, and after (i suppose) timer ends, another instance of Main window is created. But what i would like to understand is why my code didn't work. I commented the sleep thread and did some actual calculations 
'splashTimer.Start(); 
splashScr.SplashInfo = "Loading ....";
//some calculations
splashScr.SplashInfo = "Loading 2....";
//some calculations
splashTimer.Stop();'

Comment: In my answer I tried t explain why your code does not work. With a task, we allow the UI thread to continue the work (update the label), and don't block the execution with a sleep method. To avoid a second main window appear, remove the "StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" part from the App.xaml.

Comment: That did it:) Thank You very much but I need to educate myself a bit on that part because i still don't fully get it:) Once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but for me it looks like you need some code like the following in your startup:

```
SplashScr.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> (this.yourLabelChangerFunction);
```

And some function that changes the label:

```
public void yourLabelChangerFunction (object sender, EventArgs e){...}
```

Also, you seem to be setting string _SplashInfo before the window has been created, so maybe that's another reason why the window label doesn't change.

Comment: String is set after creating the splash windows:
'Splash splashScr = new Splash();
        splashScr.Show();

        splashScr.SplashInfo = "Ładowanie ....";' 
And the first thing You sugested I really don't know how to do:( Sorry noob here:(

Comment: I don't see a part in your code where you effectively change your SplashScr.label. I mean, maybe you have it somewhere else in your code, but you need some function that takes care of that when the event raises. And with the first line I suggested (that should be included inside your App.OnStartup()), you can make sure that when the event raises, the function called is that one.

Comment: 'splashScr.SplashInfo = "Ładowanie ....";' this sets the value of label content because it's binded to that property

Answer (score 0):

I think the binding is working but the window is not updated because you do Thread.Sleep in the Thread of the Splash window. You have to do it in its own Thread.

Comment: Thread.Sleep is called after changing the label content so that's not the problem.